# How to assign the access control list (ACL) when writing a CSV file to AWS in pyspark (2.2.0)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, pyspark, acl

I know I can output my spark dataframe to AWS S3 as a CSV file by

```
df.repartition(1).write.csv('s3://my-bucket-name/df_name')
```

My question is that is there an easy way to set the Access Control List (ACL) of this file to `'bucket-owner-full-control'` when writing it to S3 using pyspark?

Answer (score 2):

Access Control List (ACL) can be set via Hadoop Configuration after building spark session.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('YourAppName').getOrCreate()
```

Set ACL as below:

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3.canned.acl', 'BucketOwnerFullControl')
```

Reference: [s3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-s3-acls.html)

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the exact same issue. Spark job wrote files to a bucket that had server side encryption set to **Access Denied**. After reading some blogs, I learned that this can be solved by setting the `fs.s3a.acl.default` parameter to `BucketOwnerFullControl`. 
Here is the code:

```
val spark =SparkSession.builder.appName().getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about the EMR s3 connector; in the ASF S3A connector you set the option `fs.s3a.acl.default` when you open the connection: you can't set it on a file-by-file basis

Comment: I'm still getting this error after put object on my S3 bucket, even all these configurations.

Does anyone overcome this issue recently?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue recently and I've tried the above mentioned
I'm getting this error 'RemoteContext' object has no attribute 'hadoopConfiguration'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).