# Pyspark 2.4.0 hadoopConfiguration to write to S3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

Pyspark version 2.4.0

I'm writing files to an S3 I don't own. Then everyone is having trouble reading the file.
I think the issue is similar to this [How to assign the access control list (ACL) when writing a CSV file to AWS in pyspark (2.2.0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673924/how-to-assign-the-access-control-list-acl-when-writing-a-csv-file-to-aws-in-py)

But the solution seems no longer working. 
Searched across Pyspark doc but didn't get an answer. 
I tried:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.\
    builder.\
    master("yarn").\
    appName(app_name).\
    enableHiveSupport().\
    getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
```

This is giving me:
ERROR - {"exception": "'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'hadoopConfiguration'"

Comment: Did you try `spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues at hand.

1. In order to set new config, you need to `getOrCreate()` your `SparkSession` again with the new `config`. You won't be able to just `set`. For example:

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '1g')])

# stop the sparkContext and set new conf
sc.stop()
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

2. In order to set Hadoop Config, you need to prepend them with `spark.hadoop`. This means your config will become

```
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")])
```

Hope this helps.